# OTP and truecaller based Custom Auth flow in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito Custom Auth (OTP based login) for authenticating mobile app users. Now I want to introduce Truecaller based login, for which I need to add support in Custom Auth to verify truecaller signature.

The Cognito custom auth flow is like [image: this]

I was thinking of a approach where in I could pass a parameter (truecaller/otp) in `InitiateAuthFlow` using `ClientMetadata` field which I was hoping would reach `Define Auth Challenge` trigger on the basis of which I can decide which custom auth flow to trigger, but the documentation says it does not pass `ClientMetadata` field params to `Define Auth Challenge` trigger, I can't understand why.

And now I can't find a way to achieve this. Can someone help here?